# Why just 4 square roots given ($x^2 \bmod N$)

Tags: modular-arithmetic, cryptography

[Oblivious transfer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oblivious_transfer) algorithm's page on Wikipedia claims:

> The receiver picks a random $x$ modulo $N$ and sends $x^2 \bmod N$ to the sender
>   Note that $\gcd(x,N)=1$ with overwhelming probability, which ensures that
>   there are $4$ square roots of $x^2 \bmod N$.

The main idea here is that given $N$ and $x^2 \bmod N$, there are $4$ and only $4$ possible $x$ values that can be deduced.

Why is that? Or what did I get wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$N$ here is the product of two primes.  Modulo a prime there are at most two square roots of any number, because $x^2 - a^2 = (x-a)(x+a)$. Use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: Thanks for the `Chinese Remainder Theorem` hint, but could you please detail how to reach the equality? ($x^2−a^2=(x−a)(x+a)$)

Comment: Try it mod $5,15,105$ in a spreadsheet. There will be $2,4,8$ square roots. Powers of $2$ are special because $x^2=1$ has four solutions $\pmod 8$